# Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/tikznode'

Tags: tcolorbox, pgfkeys

I'm trying some features of [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package and I'm facing some problem with the option `$tikznode$`.
Here my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \listfiles
    \begin{document}
    \tcbset{colframe=blue!50!black, colback=white, fonttitle=\bfseries, center title}
   \begin{tcolorbox}
   Hello\newline word
   \end{tcolorbox}
   \tcbox{Hello\newline word}
   \tcbox[tikznode]{Hello\newline word}
   \end{document}
```

No problem with the first two boxes but the last one leads to an error:

> Package `pgfkeys` Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/tikznode' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `\usepackage{tikz}` in the preamble.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \listfiles
    \begin{document}
    \tcbset{colframe=blue!50!black, colback=white, fonttitle=\bfseries, center title}
   \begin{tcolorbox}
   Hello\newline word
   \end{tcolorbox}
   \tcbox{Hello\newline word}
   \tcbox[tikznode]{Hello\\ word}
   \end{document}
```

On the other hand, you can load the `tcolorbox` library `skins` which loads `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
```

Essence is `tikznode` needs `tikzpicture` and places the contents in a `tikz` node.

Comment: Thank you but the two methods did not solve the problem. Actually I’m getting really confused: after some checks, I noticed that the ‘tikz’ package is not found in my miktex package manager and when I run **mpm --admin --verify=tikz** on cmd prompt (win7), it told me that it didn’t succeed.

Comment: But when I run the following code: '\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}'  everything seems fine and I got a circle as an output. I really misunderstand such behavior. However it is all OK concerning the pgf package and tcolorbox package. I’m wondering if there is way to ensure that the required packages in the example are correctly installed (I installed a full distribution of miktex without any error in the last two days).

Comment: @Radhouane: `TiKZ` is part of `pgf` package. An independent `tikz` package doesn't exist. `TiKZ` is a kind of macro language which hides `pgf` complexity and which is what really does the work.

Comment: @Ignasi: I realized that. In fact the operating system (win 7) placed the miktex distribution in .. AppData\Roaming folder since I allowed only the administrator to be the only user. When I updated the pgf package the OS used the default installation path (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9). That is why it bugged. I fixed it and now I won my LaTeX back. Thanks to all of you.